# Loop through pages OR page breaks?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm basically trying to create a cumulative word count for documents that will put the number of words on each page into its footer and add it to the total words each page. After a lot of looking around, I found that Word doesn't really handle pages the same for everybody and so doesn't have any interface to access the individual pages through.

Now I'm trying to separate each page with page breaks so there's a clear delimiter between pages, but I still can't find how to loop through these. Any clues?

I'm going to post the code I have, but it's only for getting the word count currently. No proper attempts at cycling through page breaks because I don't know how.

```
Sub getPageWordCount()

Dim iPgNum As Integer
Dim sPgNum As String
Dim ascChar As Integer
Dim rngPage As Range
Dim iBeginPage As Integer
Dim iEndPage As Integer
' Go to start of document and make sure its paginated correctly.
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
ActiveDocument.Repaginate

' Loop through the number of pages in the document.
For iPgNum = 2 To Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
sPgNum = CStr(iPgNum)
iBeginPage = Selection.Start
' Go to next page
Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, sPgNum
' and to the last character of the previous page...
Selection.MoveLeft wdCharacter, 1, wdMove
iEndPage = Selection.Start
' Retrieve the character code at insertion point.
Set rngPage = ActiveDocument.Range(iBeginPage, iEndPage)
MsgBox rngPage.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
'rngPage.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = rngPage.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
'ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Footers
' Check the character code for hard page break or text.
Next

' ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "bob" 'Testing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it, managed to guess my way through it a bit, taking assorted bits from dark corners of the internet:

```
Sub getPageWordCount()

    'Replace all page breaks with section breaks
    Dim myrange1 As Range, myrangedup As Range
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        Do While .Execute(findText:="^m", Forward:=True, _
            MatchWildcards:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
            Set myrange = Selection.Range
            Set myrangedup = Selection.Range.Duplicate
            myrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            myrange.InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage
            myrangedup.Delete
        Loop
    End With

    'Unlink all footers and insert word count for each section
    Dim sectionCount, sectionNumber, i, sectionWordCount, cumulativeWordCount As Integer
    sectionCount = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    For sectionNumber = 1 To sectionCount
        With ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber)
            sectionWordCount = .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
            cumulativeWordCount = cumulativeWordCount + sectionWordCount
            With .Footers.Item(1)
                .LinkToPrevious = False
                .Range.Text = "This page's word count: " + CStr(sectionWordCount) + "  |  Cumulative word count: " + CStr(cumulativeWordCount)
                .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            End With
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

And now I've just discovered that if I want to port this macro to an add-in for ease of use for non-techy users I have to write it in VB 2010 in Visual Studio where the API is different. Good luck me!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have what you need, but I was working on an alternative that I may as well post because it does not require you to add page breaks or section breaks. But you would have to add the same nested field in each footer that appears in the document (I haven't done that part here, but it's not completely trivial because there may be multiple sections and multiple footers per section).

The field code you need to add (in addition to your 'This page's word count: ' text) is

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "s{ SECTION }p{ PAGE \*arabic }" }
```

As written, the method may break in some circumstances, e.g. if there are continuous section breaks. I haven't checked.

```
Sub createWordCounts()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    Set rng = .GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, i).Bookmarks("\page").Range
    .Variables("s" & CStr(rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)) & "p" & CStr(rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber))).Value = rng.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
    Set rng = Nothing
  Next
End With

End Sub
```